# Interior of a set notation

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

I'm trying to match this:

[image]

I've already tried (in amsmath)

```
$A^0$
$A^o$
$A^\circ$
```

None of these match the above image however.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It could be `$A^{\mathrm{o}}$`. Can you add a source for such a notation?

Comment: Unfortunately with that the circle is too low, but definitely matches it better than the others (but not perfectly). As for a source, the image was taken from a scan. (I would like to confirm that I am user99133 but had somehow managed to post under a guest account)

Comment: font differences are to be expected, but what is the intended meaning, is that an index 0 or a superscipt O when taken in context?

Comment: It's the interior of the set A, usually seen in topology. The index is much closer to an o rather than a 0. As for font differences, I understand that but would like to match it as close as possible.

Comment: wikipedia suggests that it is ^o  with a lowercase o https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_%28topology%29

Comment: It is indeed a lowercase o, but is there a way to raise the \mathrm{o}?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The symbol seems to be an upright “o”; in order to raise it more than it would be with `$A^{\mathrm{o}}$`, you can define a macro.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\interior}[1]{%
  {\kern0pt#1}^{\mathrm{o}}%
}

\begin{document}

$\interior{A} \interior{B}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is perfect, thank you very much! I would choose this as the answer if I could but I have no idea how to get back into the guest account. So instead, take an upvote.

Comment: @IrregularUser See http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: @egreg. Why has the 0pt kern  the effect of raising the exponent?  I can't understand.

Comment: @User In this case TeX ignores the metric information of `A` and just looks at the height of the box, because the nucleus of the math atom is not a single math character.

Answer (score 23):

The latex kernel contains the `\mathring` accent for that:

[image]

*Edit* :

You might prefer to use  the `\ring` command from `mathabx`. Here is a code to use it without replacing all maths fonts: it defines the `\abxring` mathaccent.

```
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathb}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathb}{m}{n}{ <-6> matha5 <6-7> matha6 <7-8>
mathb7 <8-9> mathb8 <9-10> mathb9 <10-12> mathb10 <12-> mathb12 }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathb}{U}{mathb}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathAccent{\abxring}{0}{mathb}{"38}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathb}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathb}{m}{n}{ <-6> matha5 <6-7> matha6 <7-8>
mathb7 <8-9> mathb8 <9-10> mathb9 <10-12> mathb10 <12-> mathb12 }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathb}{U}{mathb}{m}{n}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

I'd use the first, but take your pick:-)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}


\[
A^\mathrm{o}
\quad
A\strut^\mathrm{o}
\quad
A\mkern-1mu\vrule width0pt height 1em^\mathrm{o}
\quad
A\mkern-1mu{\vrule width0pt height 2ex}^\mathrm{o}
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Above all, use a macro, that way you can change it later (or even provide it with a few intelligence), here's a basic version

```
\newcommand*\interior[1]{#1^{\mathsf{o}}}
```

You can let `\interior` be intelligent, and do `(#1)^{\mathsf{o}}` in case there are a few symbols inside, or even some parenthesis above the whole expression like some notations do.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the game, but I’m surprised no one suggested `\circ`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\pagestyle{empty}

\newcommand\interior[1]{{#1}^{\circ}}

\begin{document}
\[ \interior{A}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Computer Modern sample]

If you want bold symbols for sets, you might try `\mathbfit` from `isomath` or `\symbfit` from `unicode-math`.